# Play - Disable Slick logging while running tests

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have added the following to my logback.xml file which logs the queries that Slick is making:

```
<!-- Inside logback.xml -->
<logger name="slick" level="INFO" />
<logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG" />
```

How can I disable this while running my tests?  (`sbt test`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tests are not [forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html) a new JVM, it will be suffice to pass the `logger.resource` parameter when running the tests, like [documented here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger#Using--Dlogger.resource):

```
sbt -Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml test
```

Of course, you need to create a `conf/loback-test.xml` file with the desired configuration. Disclaimer: I'm not a hundred percent sure if you need the command above or the one below:

```
sbt -J-Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml test
```

If you are forking (`fork := true` in your `build.sbt`) a new JVM to run the tests, then you need to [configure the parameter above to the forked JVM](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Forking.html#Forked+JVM+options). To do so, add the following line to your `build.sbt`:

```
javaOptions in test += "-Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml"
```

Again, you will need to create `conf/logback-test.xml` file.

Comment: I tried using this to disable debug logging for HikariCP but had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work with `sbt -Dlogger.resource` (or `-Dlogger.file`) for me.

Although I'm not forking a new JVM to run the tests, the only way that works is:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml"
```

added in my `build.sbt`.

Please not that it is `in Test` with an uppercase T.